# How to write in db with firebase function not as admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write on firebase function some data to DB when some http triggers ,my issue I didn't find any examples how is it possible to do without admin permission because I still want firebase rules to be taken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `event.data.ref`. From the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#ref):

> Returns a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) to the Database location where the triggering write occurred. This `Reference` has the same end-user permissions as the client that did the write. So, if an unauthenticated client did the write, this `Reference` is unauthenticated. If the client that did the write is authenticated as a certain Firebase Auth user, this `Reference` is authenticated as that same user.

Comment: is it possible to login user by email only from function in order to be strict ?

Comment: event.data.ref is already authenticated to the user the performed the write that triggered the event.  Are you saying you want a different user than that?  FYI it might actually be easier not to use security rules and instead manage everything in Cloud Functions code.

Comment: If you want to impersonate a different user than the one that triggered the write, you could pass in their uid as shown in this section in the documentation. But as Doug commented, that is quite an uncommon use-case

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an *event* object on a http-trigger (only *req* and *res*). @FrankvanPuffelen are you missing a link in your comment above about the possibility to pass a uid?

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that user-scoped references are no longer available as shown here since version 1.0 of the functions SDK.

Comment: Is it accessible inside the Callable function in Cloud functions with was recently provided?