# Firebase security rules data.exists() not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Following the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase) I created a simple security rule and cloud function that gets called to see if a username already exists. The problem is that the security rule write check always passes and just sets the new value in that location (/username_lookup/user1).

When I try to write at this location using the realtime database rules simulator it works as expected, i.e. the write is blocked.

Can someone spot the problem?

The firebase security rule

```
"rules": {    
 "username_lookup": {
  "$username": {
     // not readable, cannot get a list of usernames!
     // can only write if this username is not already in the db
     ".write": "!data.exists()",

     // can only write my own uid into this index
     ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
  }
 }
}
```

And the cloud function

```
var fb = admin.database().ref();
createUser(uid, username);

function createUser(userId, usrname) {
    fb.child('username_lookup').child(usrname).set(userId, function(unerr) {
        if(unerr) { 
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "the_error_code" }));
         }
     }); 
 }
```

Screenshot of the username_lookup object/index
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Cloud Functions access the Firebase database through:

```
var fb = admin.database().ref();
```

As you can see, the module is `admin` which indicates that you're using the Firebase Admin SDK. One of the key traits of the Firebase Admin SDK is:

> Read and write Realtime Database data with full admin privileges.

*source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup*

So the Admin SDK actually bypasses your security rules.

It's also a pretty bad practice to use an error handler for basic flow control.

Instead, use a Firebase transaction to read/write the location with the name in an atomic way:

```
fb.child('username_lookup').child(usrname).transaction(function(value) {
    if (value) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "the_error_code" }));
        return; // abort the transaction
    }
    else {
        return userId;
    }
});
```

Comment: As always, I appreciate the answer! I am having trouble finding documentation on how to obtain a non admin database reference. I read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615920/how-to-write-in-db-with-firebase-function-not-as-admin (fyi the link in the answer is a 404) however that is based off of a trigger and using the event object. In my cloud function I am using a post request. Will I need to import another Firebase SDK to get a non admin reference?